# A singular behavior about a Registration form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a registration form in my (project of) website of the following form: (i used bootstrap   framework):

```
<div id="main-box" class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            <div id="signup">
                <div id="float"></div>
                <div id="center_signup">
                    <h3>Registrazione Studente</h3> 
                    <?php if (isset($registerError)): ?>
                        <p><?php htmlout($registerError); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome: </label> 
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email: </label> 
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password: </label> 
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Now the data of the form are managed from a index.php controller file, which do this (the register.html.php file is the template file in which there is the code above):

```
if (isset($_GET['register']))
{   
    include 'register.html.php';

    if (!isset($_POST['email']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or 
    !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '')
    {
        $GLOBALS['registerError'] = 'fill in both fields';
        exit();
    }

    $password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'figarodb');

    if (databaseContainsUser($_POST['email'], $password))
    {
        $GLOBALS['registerError'] = 'Student already registered.';
        exit();
    }

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/figaro/includes/db.inc.php';

    // Puts the student in the relevant table
    try
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO studente SET 
                    nome = :nome,
                    email = :email, 
                    password = :password';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':nome', $_POST['nome']);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->bindValue(':password', $password);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Errore in student registration.';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/figaro/includes/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
```

This header might redirect at the home page, but it doesn't do it!
If instead of the page with bootstrap and javascript code, i modify the registration page in this way:

```
<body>
    <h1>Registration</h1>       
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php if (isset($registerError)): ?>
            <p><?php echo $registerError; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Nome completo: <input type="text" name="nome"
                id="nome"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: <input type="text" name="email"
                id="email"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password: <input type="password"
                name="password" id="password"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Invio">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

now the controller redirect at the home page correctly!
I can not explain this behavior, any help will be greatly appreciated!Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file there is written :

```
header('Location: .');
```

Maybe your web application is redirected on index.html by default because it's the default root.

Comment: Also index.php is the default root, if you open a web application on a folder with an index.php file, it will be opened by default.

Comment: it's a very strange mistake for me

Comment: So index.php is your default page. Change the header location for another redirection

Comment: I have made it, but: in the case of the second template (without bootstrap and javascript code) the redirection works. in the first case, when i added the bootstrap CSS and javascript code, not work, and the browser redirect to the "/localhost/mysite/?register" page in wich there is the template.

Comment: I do not know if I explained well...sorry for my bad english

Comment: Moreover, in both cases the data is actually stored in the database, but in the first case of the template, is not made the redirect

Comment: I understand.
On your first code, replace tag 'button' by 'input' for the submit.

Comment: You want to be redirected to what page? (i don't know the names of your pages)

Comment: in my index.php file there is a "include first.html.php", so i want to redirect it to this page. when i redirect to the index.php file, it might process this include, and that is what makes when the template page is in the simple form, without bootstrap CSS and javascript code..

Comment: The $_GET('register') variable, is activated from a link in the first.html.php page, if it helps you understand

Comment: `<form action="#" method="post">` test this

Comment: again, what happens is that now in the browser appear this: "/localhost/mysite/?register#".

Comment: It seems that the reference "?register" remains activated

Comment: If you want to desactive "?register" :
`<form action="index.php" method="post">`
and add `<input type='hidden' name='register' value='true'/>` in the form. In the php file replace the first _if_ by: `if (isset($_POST['register']))`

Comment: Oo sorry `<form action="register.html.php" method="post">` and your location : `header('Location: index.php?{some params}');`

Comment: In this way: in the template adding, as you suggested, <form action="index.php" method="post">, and <input type='hidden' name='register' value='true'/>

Comment: In the controller, separating the call of the template page 'register.html.php': "if ($_GET['register_stud']) { include 'register.html.php'; exit(); } from the storage of data: if ($_POST['register']) { //store; ... header('Location: .'); exit(); }

Comment: I don't see the difference between the first and second code the form. It's possible the problem is in another location.

Comment: In your second suggestion, i don't understand why this code: <form action="register.html.php" method="post">. it doesn't do a calling to the template page, again?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'm going crazy behind this code, but it is very strange that there is another problem

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, your help has been fundamental